# Can I use ESP32-S3 as USB HUB or USB HOST for USB data communication?

Tags: usb, libusb, usb-drive, usbserial, uistatusbar

I have a system consisting of a computer and various sensors. The sensors have a USB communication interface. I want to design GPIO and communication card between computer and sensors. I want to read the data from the sensor (Usb interface) with a microprocessor (ESP32-S3), pass it through various processes and send it to the computer (Usb interface). I have tried usb CDC ACM and HID sample codes but failed. Can I use ESP32-S3 as USB HUB or USB HOST for USB data communication? If possible, where could I be making a mistake?

I programmed an Esp32-S3 as if it were a sensor. With another Esp32-S3, I was able to send the data I received with the USb protocol to the computer. But I was not successful with other sensors.